# Why does this work in ISE but not when launched from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, powershell-ise

If I run this script in Powershell ISE it works, but when it is launched from a batch file, it does not work. The script is [here(clicky)](http://pastebin.com/z1G955Bf). The batch file that launches this is [here(clicky)](http://pastebin.com/rV8gQ3wq).

When launched from the batch file, powershell writes (0) and it does not work. When launched from ISE, powershell writes (1) and then works.

Also, I did confirm that the script is being run, but not correctly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It may seem like you're double-quoting the path to the script. Also, Why are you using PowerShell to start another PowerShell to call the file? Try:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath="%ThisScriptsDirectory%\data\Start.ps1"
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %PowerShellScriptPath%
```

Comment: I am using this as a batch file, which then calls the Powershell file. And this does the same thing, but in a batch window rather than a powershell window.

Comment: And why is that a bad thing? The only difference is that it uses the cmd-window(btw a powershell window is the same console only with a blue background) until the script is done. If you want to run it in a separate window, use `start /wait PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %PowerShellScriptPath%`. `PowerShell.exe` is slow to start and uses lots of resources, so you would want to create as few processes as possible.

Comment: Details? Are there any errors? if so, include them in your question.